# Python(flask)--how to get a value from a data without 'for loop'

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Python. I've got the question.

here's the data:

```
languages =[
{'name': 'java','version': '2.0'}, 
{'name': 'python',"version": "3"}, 
{'name': 'ruby','version': '2.3'}
]
```

python code:

```
@app.route('/test3/<name>', methods=['GET']) 
def test3(name):
    for language in languages:
        if language['name'] == name: 
            return jsonify([language])
    return ("err")
```

so if I want to get the ruby data, my url will be http://localhost:5000/test3/ruby
and the result will be:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ruby", 
    "version": "2.3"
  }
]
```

but how do I get the ruby data without 'for loop'?

I tried another example, if my data is:

```
data = {'1':'java', '2':'python', '3':'ruby'}
```

python code:

```
@app.route('/data/<userid>', methods=['GET']) 
def returnOneofData(userid):
    if userid in data:
        r = jsonify({userid:data[userid]})          
    else:
        r = (userid + ' is not found')
    return r
```

I use 'if else', not 'for loop'.

So that i can get ruby with the url:http://localhost:5000/data/3
and no need to use for loop.

I know these two datas are different type,
is there any way that I can get ruby from the first data(languages) without for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@app.route('/test3/<name>', methods=['GET']) 
def test3(name):
   return list(filter(lambda language: language.get('name')==name , languages))
```

Comment: It didn't work at first, cause list is not callable. But once I add jsonify(), it worked!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, You should put your data in database, and use database to save/query your data. Sqlite3 is a good database for newbies. If your data is small, and you really don't want to use database, you can save your data in a configure file (eg. a json file) and not save your data to your code directly.

As your question, I think 'for loop' is not a bad choice for small size data. If you don't like it, you can change your data struct like your second data:

```
languages ={
  'java':{'version': '2.0'}, 
  'python':{'version': '3'}, 
  'ruby':{'version': '2.3'}
}
```

and use your 'if else' to do this.

You can also use another 'for loop' format.

```
[language for language in language if language['name']=='ruby'
```

Comment: thank you, but this is just a small demo, I need to run it with a big size data eventually. I'm wondering if there are other ways such as find or search in python, make the performance better than do it with 'for loop'. Besides, our data format cannot change. Thank u anyways.

Comment: I think you should use database

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data follows the same format, you can transform the data to a dictionary of language-version pairs for simple, efficient lookup. The `dict.get` function can be utilized to access the value via key, and a default error value can be provided if the language is not found:

```
languages = [{'name': 'java', 'version': '2.0'}, {'name': 'python', 'version': '3'}, {'name': 'ruby', 'version': '2.3'}]
new_languages = dict(i.values() for i in languages)
#{'java': '2.0', 'python': '3', 'ruby': '2.3'}

@app.route('/test3/<name>', methods=['GET']) 
def test3(name):
   return flask.jsonify({'lang':name, 'result':new_languages.get(name, 'ERR')})
```